# Finite temperature Greens function simplification

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, greens-functions, topological-insulators

I am currently studying topological insulators using Topological insulators and superconductors by Bernevig. In chapter 3, section 3.2.2, he has derived the finite temperature Green's function using spectral functions as:

$$G^T(\omega_m)=\frac{-1}{\beta}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1-e^{-\beta\omega'})\frac{J_1(\omega')}{i\omega_m-\omega'}\frac{d\omega'}{2\pi} \quad .$$

Later on in section 3.3, he says that the explicit form of the finite temperature Green's function is:

$$G^T(k,\omega_n)=\frac{1}{i\omega_n-h(k)} \quad ,$$

where $h(k)$ is somehow related to the Hamiltonian's components, not sure what exactly it would mean here, because I do not understand how he got here. He is basically calculating the response function. He Fourier transforms the above explicit green's function to simplify the response function, so as to get the conductivity tensor. So basically, I do not understand, how can we go from that integral to this compact form?

Comment: Please add some context and a more detailed reference (chapter, page, eq. numbers)...